# Java File.setReadable() doesn't work on Windows

Tags: java, linux, windows

I have this code and I want to test a function when a not readable file is passed by parameter. The function doesn't matter here, only the fact that File.setReadble(false) seems not working only on Windows.

The `File` class is obsolete, so how can I guarantee if a file is readable or not independent of platform?

I tested the same code on Linux and Mac, the test worked correctly.

```java
    @Test
    public void testReadableFile2() {
        System.out.println("testReadableFile2");
        URL resource = TestClass.class.getResource("/xml/file.xml");
        assertNotNull(resource);
        Path file = null;
        try {
            file = Paths.get(resource.toURI());
        } catch (final URISyntaxException ex) {
            System.out.println("exception: " + ex);
        }

        assertNotNull(file);
        assertTrue(Files.exists(file));

        // Query file system
        FileStore fileStore = null;
        try {
            fileStore = Files.getFileStore(file);
        } catch (final IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("IOException for get file store: " + ex);
        }

        assertNotNull(fileStore);

        boolean isReadable = true;
        if (fileStore.supportsFileAttributeView(DosFileAttributeView.class)) {
            boolean hadException = false;
            try {
                // Set read-only
                DosFileAttributeView att = Files.getFileAttributeView(file, DosFileAttributeView.class);
                att.setReadOnly(true);
                isReadable = !att.readAttributes().isReadOnly();
            } catch (final IOException ex) {
                System.out.println("IOException for set attribute: " + ex);
                hadException = true;
            }
            assertFalse(hadException);

        } else if (fileStore.supportsFileAttributeView(PosixFileAttributeView.class)) {
            boolean hadException = false;
            try {
                // Change permissions
                PosixFileAttributes attrs = Files.readAttributes(file, PosixFileAttributes.class);
                Set<PosixFilePermission> newPermissions = attrs.permissions();
                newPermissions.remove(PosixFilePermission.OWNER_READ);
                newPermissions.remove(PosixFilePermission.OTHERS_READ);
                newPermissions.remove(PosixFilePermission.GROUP_READ);

                Files.setPosixFilePermissions(file, newPermissions);

                PosixFileAttributeView newAttr = Files.getFileAttributeView(file, PosixFileAttributeView.class);
                newAttr.setPermissions(newPermissions);

                boolean owner, others, group;

                owner = newAttr.readAttributes().permissions().contains(PosixFilePermission.OWNER_READ);
                others = newAttr.readAttributes().permissions().contains(PosixFilePermission.OTHERS_READ);
                group = newAttr.readAttributes().permissions().contains(PosixFilePermission.GROUP_READ);
                isReadable = !owner && !others && !group;
            } catch (final IOException ex) {
                System.out.println("io exception: " + ex);
                hadException = true;
            }
            assertFalse(hadException);
        }

        assertFalse(isReadable);

        assertFalse(Files.isReadable(file)); // assertion failure here
    }
```

I get an asseertion failure on the last line.

Anybody can help me on this problem?

Comment: What's the value of `someValidPath`?

Comment: java.io.File is obsolete.  Avoid using it as much as possible.  Instead, use the [java.nio.file](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/package-summary.html) package.  Use `Paths.get(someValidPath)`, and `Files.setAttribute(path, "dos:readonly", false)` (if in Windows) or `Files.setPosixFilePermissions(path, PosixFilePermissions.fromString("rw-rw-rw-"))` (if not in Windows).  Those methods, unlike java.io.File methods, will always either work as expected or throw an exception.

Comment: How do I validate it on Windows and Linux/Mac? I'm using a test and `Files.isReadable` is not working, I will update my question

Comment: `isReadable = !att.readAttributes().isReadOnly()` I think this is a mistake. `isReadOnly` means it cannot be written to. It has no relation to being readable.